# How to make a UIImageView draggable?

Tags: uiimageview, draggable

I am am a beginner iOS developer and I am trying to make an app that involves the user moving an image around the screen (dragging an image, really). Could someone help me with this? I would also like for the user not to be able to drag the image off the screen. Thanks!
I have tried the following code in a subclass of UIImageView:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];

}
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
CGRect frame = [self frame];
frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
[self setFrame: frame];
}
```

It's showing an error in the three lines that use start location ("Use of undeclared identifier 'startLocation'"). Could someone help me fix this error?

Comment: Have You tried to implement anything? If so, please, share the code.

Comment: Just edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it I just had to declare it before the methods.